# Create a custom gauge with an image Objective C

Tags: objective-c, image, gauge

I want to create a custom gauge for my application, which will show a heart shape, animated to  fill from bottom to top.

I do not understand how to create this effect.

Comment: Hey Willy, you haven't explained what "a lot of research is". SpriteKit could allow you to build this easily, or you could use some 3D (for example with Metal), or you could use Core Animation. However, you did not tell us what your requirement is. We don't even know if it's on the Mac or on the iPhone that you want to make this "app". Also, given this is a relatively simple task, I wonder why you use Objective-C instead of the more modern Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many solutions, given the fuzziness of the question, is to use Core Animation. The official Apple documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Let's outline three steps:

- *Conceptual step* Define what layers (conceptually) or masks you will use, and create the images that will be imported in them
- *Definition step* Define your `CABasicAnimation` and program the layers
- *Animation step* Apply your modifications

Let's go through the details.

***Conceptual step***

Let's assume you choose to have three layers:

- background
- empty heart shape (for example, a nice silver line, or maybe just nothing)
- filled heart shape (for example, a nice gem cut in the shape of a heart, or jelly, or an Apple-red-skin... ask your artist)

At this point, your artist have provided you with 6 files if you're building for iPad. Let's assume the following names and types.

`| Name | Type|
|:-----:|:––––:|
|background.jpg| background picture for iPad Mini |
|background@2x.jpg|background picture for iPad Retina and up |
|heartenclosure.png| heart border picture for iPad Mini |
|heartenclosure@2x.png|heart border picture for iPad Retina and up |
|heartbody.png| heart contents picture for iPad Mini |
|heartbody@2x.png|heart contents picture for iPad Retina and up |`

Once you have these as JPG/PNG files, you import them into Xcode. Pay attention to have the Retina (and iPhone 6+), with double and triple size. You will drag and drop these into a file called `Images.xcassets`, which is (pretty much) your "image store".

***Definition step***

The plan is to have the background be static, the heart contents be animated from the current height to the new height anytime the jauge updates, and the heart border as the top layer.

Let's build the background image:
`UIImage* backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];`
and the same code will create the top picture:
`UIImage* heartshapeImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heartenclosure"];`

iOS is smart enough to select the correct image, you don't have to pass in the JPG or @2x information. By default, the z-index of images added to the display is "latest on top".

Once the picture is built, it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/9YUGZmz) on my iPhone (my apologies to the original artist).

What we'll do, and again it's only one of many possibilities, is create three `CALayers` and add them as the `UIView`'s layers sublayers.
For my own sake I've made a [heart shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97F3s.jpg) based on a nice heart [found with Google](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/lostpedia/images/b/b9/6326-tatice-Coeur.png/revision/latest?cb=20070603001311&path-prefix=fr). In your project you'll want the real art I was suggesting earlier ;)

The code for building the layer goes into `- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` (because at this point, the frame is already set).

Note the name being set on the heart layer, which will allow us to animate it.

UIImage* backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
    UIImage* heartImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Coeur"];
    UIImage* heartShapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Coeurshape"];

```
CALayer* backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
backgroundLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
backgroundLayer.opacity = 1;
backgroundLayer.opaque = YES;
backgroundLayer.hidden = NO;
backgroundLayer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 20, 20);
backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.1 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0]CGColor];
backgroundLayer.contents = (__bridge id) backgroundImg.CGImage;
backgroundLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer ];

CALayer* heartLayer =[CALayer layer];
heartLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
heartLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
heartLayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
heartLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
heartLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
heartLayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 80, 200);
heartLayer.contents = (__bridge id) heartImage.CGImage;
heartLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
[heartLayer setName:@"heartLayer"];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:heartLayer];

CALayer* heartShapeLayer =[CALayer layer];
heartShapeLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
heartShapeLayer.frame = heartLayer.frame;
heartShapeLayer.contents = (__bridge id)(heartShapeImage.CGImage);
heartShapeLayer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:heartShapeLayer];
```

*** Animation Step***

By changing the bounds of the heartLayer using `CABasicAnimation`, with masks enabled: `heartLayer.masksToBounds = YES;` you can then show the amount of heart you wish.

In order to access your sublayer, you'll need to use its name.
This subroutine does the trick:

```
- (CALayer *)findLayerByName:(NSString*) layerTagName inLayer:(CALayer*) layer{

    for (CALayer *layer in [layer sublayers]) {

        if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:layerTagName]) {
            return layer;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note that, as per my earlier comment, using Swift is a good option. Ray Wenderlich's website has a nice article about [UIView animations in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76200/basic-uiview-animation-swift-tutorial).

Comment: If you are going to downvote the answer, let him know why at least.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! To respond to my research I only found the classic gauge like, linear gauge, circle gauge, didn't find any custom gauge. Maybe I didn't search enough. It's really helpful thank you I'll give it a try ! I never used Swift before that's why I feel more confortable with Objective C. I really don't know how Swift works, and I'm not "super good" with Objective C so I prefer improve in Objective C before start learning how to use Swift maybe I'm wrong let me know ! And sorry if my question is not that constructive but I really found nothing.

Comment: I've added the basics, which shows the elements that make up the layer. I've also described the rest of the solution. I'll post the code once I have time to actually write/test it so you have a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kheldar, it's really helpful for me ! Everything works fine. But I didn't get how the animation works, I tried to use CABasicAnimation but the only thing I succeeded to do is to change the size by changing the bounds. sorry I'm new how can we insert code in our moment ?

Comment: @WillyKim I've made a project on GitHub with some code in it for you to see. Also, if you don't care that much about the speed at which the animation runs, don't forget that Apple will run animations automatically when you change parameter values. I have a branch that demonstrates that behaviour in the repo. I haven't finished the mask branch yet, I'll try to spend some time on this.

Comment: @Kheldar I would like to take a look at it ! Thank you for helping me. I don't care that much about speed I guess.

Comment: @WillyKim I forgot to give the link.... https://github.com/guillaumemaiano/HeartExperiment

Comment: Encountered this in the close vote queue. I guess your answer was downvoted because many people (including me) believe that low quality questions shouldn't be answered. It encourages people to use StackOverflow as an outsourcing agency. We really expect people to show some effort themselves first. Not least because it usually clearly shows what they're actually asking. That said, you really went out of your way to make this a sound answer anyway +1.